# Socket closing automatically

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Is there a reason why a Socket should close by itself, after 2h? I am receiving data every second from this socket, and writing back some tiny "keep-alive" data every 30s.

Before sending, I check if socket is still connected using the following method:

```
public bool IsSocketReadyForWriting(Socket s)
{
   try
   {
      if (!s.Connected)
      {
          Log.Info("Socket.Connected was false");
          return false;
      }

      // following line will throw if socket disconnected
      bool poll = s.Poll(2000, SelectMode.SelectWrite);
      if (!poll)
      {
         try
         {
            // if poll is false, socket is closed
            Log.Info("poll is false");
            this.Close();
         }
         catch { }
         return false;
      }
      Log.Debug("still connected");
      return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      Log.Error("Error while checking if socket connected", ex);
      return false;
   }
}
```

Everything works fine for about 2h, then suddenly Socket.Poll returns false, and the Socket gets closed.

Is there a setting which controls this, or am I doing something really wrong?

**[Edit]**

Forgot to mention: I control **both** server and client side of the link. These are both C# apps, one of them creates a listening socket, the other one opens a connection and sends data. They communicate without problems for 2h (no memory leaks and stuff), then the socket closes.

When this happens, I can reconnect the socket again easily, but I am just wandering if anyone knows why could be the reason for this.

Comment: Is the measured timeout exactly 2h? Or just round about that? Also, do you control all the network devices in between?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a TCP socket is writable when there's at least one byte of space available in the socket *send buffer*. To reverse that - the socket is *not* writable when there's enough unacknowledged data sitting in the "output queue".

That said, pull out [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) or whatever Microsoft provides for packet sniffing and see what's going on on the wire. Are your heartbeat chunks getting `ACK`-ed? Does the receiver window stay open or does it go to zero? Or are you just getting explicit `RST` or a `FIN` from some intermediate switch?

One way to mitigate temporary clogged pipe is to increase the send buffer size, which is kind of tiny by default on Windows - 8192 iirc. See the [`setsockopt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms911745.aspx) (.NET probably has a version of that) and the `SO_SNDBUF` option.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. My dummy clients weren't reading the input TCP stream (several ping/status bytes) at all, so my server output buffer got filled up.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the server that is closing the connection? Do you have control over it?

Comment: Oh, forgot to say, I control both the server and the client. They are both C# apps.

Comment: AFAIK, 2 hours is the timeout after SOL_KEEPALIVE option sends its prove (see http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.7.shtml). Could it be that this option is enabled on one side and not on the other?